# How to convert Guid[] to String?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Something like `String.Join(",", new string[] { "a", "b" });`, but for `Guid[]`

```
var guids = new Guid[] { Guid.Empty, Guid.Empty };

var str = /* Magic */

// str = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
var str = guids.Select(g => g.ToString())
               .Aggregate((working, next) => working + "," + next);
```

Once your list of Guids starts growing, this method of concatenation is going to cause performance issues. You can modify it to use a StringBuilder:

```
var str = guids.Select(g => g.ToString())
               .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                          (sb, str) => sb.Append("," + str),
                          sb => sb.ToString());
```

Both of those are the complicated LINQ Extension method way of doing things. You could also simply use String.Join:

```
var str = String.Join(",", guids.Select(g => g.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: I'd be curious at how fast it works compared to other methods. I'm guessing Aggregate doesn't use String.Concat to allocate memory correctly.

Comment: @BrunoLM - Just keep in mind that with large lists of Guids, you might run into perf issues (a lot of string concatenation). In that case, you might need to switch to the StringBuilder method (and manually remove the last comma).

Comment: I will, but SO has a delay. Just wait 3 minutes :P

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich - Aggregate will use whatever concatenation method you specify.

Comment: @Justin Niessner: Right, but if you only pass two arguments to String.Concat it won't have any improvement over the + operator. The + operator I believe, don't quote me on this, already calls the String.Concat.

Answer (score 22):

.NET 4 added a `String.Join<T>(string separator, IEnumerable<T> values` method. So, in .NET 4, just this will work:

```
String.Join(",", guids);
```

Answer (score 20):

```
String.Join(",", guids.Select(g => g.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: .NET 4 added a generic `Join` method which you can just pass the `guids` array to without modifications

Answer (score 5):

I thought this would work?

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
int i = 0;
foreach (var guid in guids)
{
    stringBuilder.Append(guid.ToString());
    if (++i < guids.Length)
    { 
        stringBuilder.Append(","); 
    }
}

var str = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: You forgot the `,` between GUIDs ;)

Comment: That will put an extra comma at the end.

Comment: Ok, I tried to fix the comma issue quickly. It's untested. I hope it works :-)

Comment: as a suggestion, I would append the comma before appending the guid, but only if the stringbuilder.length > 0

Answer (score 1):

if your framework >= .NET 3.5

```
String.Join(",", (from g in guids select g.ToString()).ToArray())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll(guids, g => g.ToString()));
```

Comment: It seems this statement can't pass compilation in VS2010?

Comment: Array.ConvertAll needs a class that implements `Converter<TInput, TOutput>`, you're passing in a method.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Convert string to List<string>    
List<string> guidList = your_string.Split(',').ToList<string>();

//Convert string to List<Guid>    
List<Guid> guidList = your_string.Split(',').ToList<string>().ConvertAll<Guid>(g => new Guid(g));
```